# Удалить уведомление при выходе из приложения

Tags: android-service, android

Имеется такой рабочий код с сайта старт андроид:

```
package ru.startandroid.develop.p0991servicenotification;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  public final static String FILE_NAME = "filename";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String fileName = intent.getStringExtra(FILE_NAME);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName))
      tv.setText(fileName);
  }

  public void onClickStart(View v) {
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
  }

  public void onClickStop(View v) {
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
  }
}
```

и сервис:

```
package ru.startandroid.develop.p0991servicenotification;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service {
  NotificationManager nm;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  }

  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sendNotif();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }

  void sendNotif() {
    // 1-я часть
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Text in status bar", 
      System.currentTimeMillis());

    // 3-я часть
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.FILE_NAME, "somefile");
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // 2-я часть
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Notification's title", "Notification's text", pIntent);

    // ставим флаг, чтобы уведомление пропало после нажатия
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // отправляем
    nm.notify(1, notif);
  }

  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Работает все на ура, только вот вопрос, может, кто знает, как удалить уведомление при закрытии приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переопределить у Activity onDestroy() и перед super.onDestroy() добавить

```
NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notifManager.cancelAll();
```

Нашел ответ в гугле за 46 сек.

Comment: Гугл чего-то подвёл. Лично у меня на всех трёх планшетах (3.0, 4.1.2 и 4.2.2) `onDestroy` не вызывается. Да и закрывать все уведомления как-то нехорошо. Вдруг автору требуется закрыть только одно определённое уведомление?

Comment: @SuperCreeper, да, но я почему-то уверен, что автор хочет закрыть все уведомления (закрыть все, которых всего 1).    
onDestroy должен вызываться. Исключения составляет ситуация, когда системе требуется память, и она попросту убивает процесс, не вызываю onDestroy. В этом случае уведомление отвалится само собой.    
@Рослан Рәхмәтуллин, а вообще правильно делать именно так, как написал @SuperCreeper.

Comment: спасибо, очень выручил

Answer (score 4):

В сервисе строка:

```
nm.notify(1, notif);
```

Создаёт уведомление с id 1. Я бы поменял его на бóльшее число, например `582962`.

Чтобы убать уведомление при выходе из приложеия, в активити переопределите `onStop`:

```
@Override
public void onStop()
{
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.cancel(вот тут должен быть id вашего уведомления);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: @SuperCreeper твой метод тоже работает, но почему то после завершение приложения, уведомление вновь всплывает... да и к тому же как выше говорилось у меня лишь одно уведомление. Возможно в твоем коде надо что то дописать, но мне проще скопировать 1 и вставить, ибо, искать решение я буду долго :D . нубяра я, что скажешь..